# How to ignore "Keycode_Enter" in Edit Text

Tags: android, encryption

i want to create a crypthography apps that can encrypt text which inserted by user from a editText.
But i got a problem when user inserting a multiline text.
Like the image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQLcc.jpg
i just don't know what to do with the multiline (i mean when user press enter and it's create a new line), i can't process it to my encryption.

So what i want ask is, is there any possible way for me to just ignore this ENTER? but if i decrypt the text, it's doesn't make the text looks crowd. 
Please friends, help me.

Comment: do you need the multi line ?

Comment: yes... i need it when decrypting the text. Because i want the decryption result is exactly same with the original text.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the multi line just limit the lines and it will be ok .

If you do need it , simply override the enter like so **code**:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
{
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
    {  // enter was pressed time to work
        String currenttext = v.getText().toString();    // current text will contain the text
        doYourThing();      
        return true;
     } 
     else 
     { //continue regulary
        return false;
     }
     }
});
```

Comment: nice idea friends... i need the multiline, but do you know how to decrypt the text with the multiline? so the result will be exactly same with the original text

Comment: i added the gettext in the code , is that what you meant ?